# Trying to change button background with a if statement

Tags: android, button, if-statement

Trying to create a game that kids chase the marble.  I want to have the buttons background change only if another buttons background equal something. But can't get the onclick with the a if statement to work. Here is the code I currently have.

```
package test.tablet.design;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MarbleGame extends Activity {

private Button btnA1mc; private Button btnA2mc; private Button btnA3mc; private Button btnA4mc; private Button btnB1mc; private Button btnB2mc; private Button btnB3mc; private Button btnB4mc;
private Button btnC1mc; private Button btnC2mc; private Button btnC3mc; private Button btnC4mc; private Button btnD1mc; private Button btnD2mc; private Button btnD3mc; private Button btnD4mc;
private Button btnE1mc; private Button btnE2mc; private Button btnE3mc; private Button btnE4mc; private Button btnF1mc; private Button btnF2mc; private Button btnF3mc; private Button btnF4mc;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.marble_chase);
    TextView tv_time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
    String currenttime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    tv_time.setText(currenttime);

    btnA1mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnA1mc); btnA2mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnA2mc); btnA3mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnA3mc); btnA4mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnA4mc);
    btnB1mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnB1mc); btnB2mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnB2mc); btnB3mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnB3mc); btnB4mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnB4mc);
    btnC1mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnC1mc); btnC2mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnC2mc); btnC3mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnC3mc); btnC4mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnC4mc);
    btnD1mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnD1mc); btnD2mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnD2mc); btnD3mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnD3mc); btnD4mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnD4mc);
    btnE1mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnE1mc); btnE2mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnE2mc); btnE3mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnE3mc); btnE4mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnE4mc);
    btnF1mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnF1mc); btnF2mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnF2mc); btnF3mc =    (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnF3mc); btnF4mc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnF4mc);

    btnE2mc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
      {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v)
          {
              btnE2mc.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.marble_x);
              btnB4mc.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.marble);
          }
      });
    btnB4mc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (btnE2mc.equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marble_x)))
            {
            btnB4mc.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.marble_x);
            btnC1mc.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.marble);
            }
            else{}
        }
    });
    btnC1mc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (btnB4mc.equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marble_x)))
            {
            btnC1mc.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.marble_x);
            btnF1mc.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.marble);
            }
            else{}
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: So you're tracking the location of the marble based on the picture that was drawn?  Wouldn't it be easier to track the current and previous locations of the marble as coordinates then draw based on that info?

Comment: Found another way to do it, thanks for your guys is help.

Answer (score 0):

I would have an internal `boolean` set to true whenever the button is clicked and the background is changed.

```
boolean isBackgroundChanged = false;
```

Whenever the button is clicked, you change the background and set `isBackgroundChanged` to `true`.
And then, instead of doing:

```
btnB4mc.equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marble_x)
```

you would have

```
if(isBackgroundChanged)...
```

Comment: Can you explain it using my code, Still learning android. Can Understand it, if I see working code.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to compare the Button object with a Drawable object, which will always return false.

You might instead want to use View.setTag() to track the state for each individual button. With a tag (named or unnamed) you can associate arbitrary data with an individual View. In the example below, auto-boxing is used to convert booleans into Booleans.

```
if ((Boolean)btn1.getTag()) {
  btn1.setTag(false);
  btn2.setTag(true);
  // TODO actual background swapping
}
```

For readability and reducing duplication, you might want to use a helper function that can do the swapping for you, which will take two Buttons as arguments.